# Hiding sensitive information in response

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am currently working in a project where I have a User model and am using a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API to fetch a list of users. (I have more entities.)

User has a password field. I do not want to include the password field in the result. So I excluded it in the [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). But when I want to create a User, I want to include the password in the request. So Spring MVC gets the User entity (not the DTO).

I don't think it is good to do so.... For example, I have Event model which is connected to user with a many-to-many relationship. I don't want that in the request. I want *only* the user. So what do you suggest me to do? Have another kind-of DTO?

Comment: unclear what you are asking - you don't want someone to see something then encrypt it

Comment: I want to exclude it from the response. I am planning to encrypt it (I am only in the beginning) but I don't it is good idea to have sensitive information in responses.

Comment: Is your response JSON?

Comment: As an aside: "User has a password field" - does this contain the password in plain text? I hope you realize that storing a plaingext password is a very unsafe practice. See for example [What are all of the issues with storing a cleartext password?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12641/what-are-all-of-the-issues-with-storing-a-cleartext-password).

Answer (score 30):

Use `@JsonIgnore` with `Access.WRITE_ONLY` for getter methods only.

Example

```
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String password;
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to serialize your response objects,  you can annotate the property in question with @JsonIgnore and it will not be included in the response.

```
public User {
    private String email;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password

    ...getters and setters

}
```

It might also be a good idea to create separate response objects that only include the fields you want in case you add sensitive fields down the road and forget to hide them.  Likewise, you would also have separate request objects for creating users that would include a password field.  Business entities, like a User, are probably best to use only internally, so you can control what information goes public.

Comment: If I `@JsonIgnore` the entire property, it will not be serialized at all. Even the setter. Perhaps annotate only the getter?

Comment: You can annotate just the getter, or follow Zico's answer by setting the access property of JsonProperty.  But check out my updated answer.  Thinking using separate request and response objects might be better practice.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid using *@JsonIgnore*, you can use [json-view library](https://github.com/monitorjbl/json-view).
For example, in your controller you can do something like this:

At first, declare this in your controller variable:

```
private JsonResult json = JsonResult.instance();
```

And then use this method:

```
@RequestMapping("/get/{id}")
public void getUserById(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id) {
    User user = usersService.findOne(id);
    json.use(JsonView.with(user)
            .onClass(User.class, Match.match()
                    .exclude("password").exclude("yetAnothertopSecretField")));
}
```

It returns JSON without excluded fields.

The JsonView and JsonResult classes are imported from the json-view library.

Answer (score 1):

I'm tried this `JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY` and it's working with me.

```
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
```

Comment: Note - this is valid for Newtonsoft.Json serializer

Comment: The [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) software: [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)

Answer (score -2):

Make the field 'password' as null while sending the response and [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) will not show that in response. Don't remove it completely from the model class.